# How to reference external aws resource with default in serverless framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I want to reference an external aws resource in serverless framework.  However, if it does not exist, I want to fall back to a default value

For example:

```js
functions:
  create:
    handler: posts.create
    events:
      - http:
          path: posts/create
          method: post
          authorizer: arn: xxx:xxx:Lambda-Name
```

For `authorizer`, I want to reference a function if it exists, and if it does not exist, to default to another value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your authorizer function is part of another cloud formation stack, you can use CloudFormation [outputs](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#reference-cloudformation-outputs) to do this. If not, there are still several other variable solutions in the [docs](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/).

To do that conditionally, you'd combine it with a default. For example:

```
 ${cf:my-stack-${self:custom.stage}.AuthorizerArn, 'some-default-arn'}
```